# LINQ querying for multiple dates and counting rows

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Hi I want to know how to do two things with LINQ
This question is probably more a SQL/C# thing I firstly want to query with multiple dates 
How would I do this?

For example I want to query every date in 2011 in a DateTime SQL Column So I want to find 01/01/2011 to 31/12/2011 I guess I would replace the first day month numbers with something e.g ##/##/2011

Secondly how do I count rows would it be like this "var rowCount = qRows.Count();"

Thanks

Comment: You answered your second question yourself.  +10!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
List<Order> ord = (from o in dc.Orders
                               where o.OrderDate.Value.Year == 2011
                               select o).ToList();

            int Count = ord.Count;
```

Comment: your solution does work, but it is better to use a between style query so that the database can use any indexes. This can make a massive difference if there are lots of rows

Answer (score 1):

```
from x in somethingwithdate
  where x.adate > '1/1/2000'
  where x.adate < '1/1/2010'
   select x
```

you can also do x.Count

Answer (score 0):

You can do `myDate.AddDays(1)` repeated as many times as necessary.

Yes, you can do a Count() on the returned LINQ dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different take on earlier answer(if you were pulling the date from another object for instance):

```
              DateTime myDate = new DateTime(2011,1,1);
                var results = (from t in dc.events
                               where t.event_date.Value.Year.Equals(myDate.Year)
                               select t).ToList();
                int testCount = results.Count();
```